# what is the return type of list initialisation?

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

Does anyone would like to explain why case 1 and case 2 have different output for this code snippet.

```
struct A {
    A() { cout << "A()" << endl; }
    A(int i) { cout << "A(int)" << endl; }
    A(const A&) { cout << "A(const A&)" << endl; }
    A(A&&) noexcept { cout << "A(A&&)" << endl; }
    A& operator=(const A&) { cout << "operator=(const A&)" << endl; return *this; }
    A& operator=(A&&) noexcept { cout << "operator=(A&&)" << endl; return *this; }
    friend bool operator< (const A&, const A&) { return true; }
};

int main() {
    std::set<A> aSet;
    aSet.insert(1);       // case 1
    //aSet.insert({1});   // case 2

    return 0;
}
```

For case 1, the output is:

```
A(int)
A(A&&)
```

and for case 2 is:

```
A(int)
A(const A&)
```

The compiler version is:

> g++ --version
>   g++-7 (SUSE Linux) 7.2.1 20170901 [gcc-7-branch revision 251580]
>   Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant overloads of [`std::set::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) are:

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( value_type const& value ); // #1
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( value_type&& value );      // #2
void insert( std::initializer_list<value_type> ilist );     // #6
```

When you call `aSet.insert(1);` that invokes #2 in preference to #1 - which is going to create a new `A` via `A(int )` and then move it into the set. Hence, `A(A&& )`.

However, when you call `aSet.insert({1})`, the overload selected is #6. Whenever you use list-initialization, the `std::initializer_list` candidate is *strongly preferred* (basically, we do overload resolution first *only* considering those candidates and then, only if we don't find one, do we redo overload resolution considering the rest). Since `std::initializer_list` is backed by a [`const` array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), once we create our `A` via `A(int )` we *must* copy it out - we cannot move it. Hence `A(A const& )`.

Comment: is that means for the list initialization constructor, we get a "const" object for compatible reasons. Since the object has a top-level const, the insert operation has to take copy constructor rather than move constructor. am I right?

Comment: @fetag There is no "list initialization constructor", and I don't know what you mean by "compatible reasons."

Comment: based on you said: " Since std::initializer_list is backed by a const array", I think this statement aSet.insert({1}) could be analogized as following: const A temp = A{1}; aSet.insert(temp);

Comment: @fetag: There is no such thing as a "list initialization constructor". It's an "initializer list constructor". The order there is important: "initializer list" is a type (`initializer_list`). List initialization is a process which may *or may not* create an initializer list.

Comment: @fetag: "*I think this statement aSet.insert({1}) could be analogized as following: const A temp = A{1}; aSet.insert(temp);*" Remember: when using list initialization, `initializer_list`s *always win*. So if it is *at all possible* to call something that takes an `initializer_list`, then list initialization will do that. That's why you have to be careful about when and where you use it.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes, but this is not the point that confused me. The question is why aSet.insert({1}); invoke the copy constructor rather than the move constructor after initializer list construct.

Comment: @fetag Because a `std::initializer_list<T>` is a proxy around an array of `T const`.

Comment: @Barry ok, this is exactly the answer that I want. big thanks! :)